# Convert .mov URL to a blob and convert blog to mp4 using javascript and in a website?

Tags: javascript, web

How do I convert `.mov` URL to a blob and convert this blob to an `.mp4` using Javascript and in a website?

But here is my attempt:

```
function convertVideo(givenURL) {

  var file = new Blob(
    [givenURL],
    {"type" : "video/mp4"});

  var mp4VideoFile = new File(
      [file],
      { "type" : 'video/mp4' });

  return mp4VideoFile
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work as you'd like it to. Javascript doesn't natively know anything about converting/writing images or movies.

Comment: IMO the best way to accomplish this would be to find or create a separate web service for video conversion, then pass the .mov data through to the service.

Comment: A `.mov` file **is** an MPEG-4 container, btw (yes, [ISO MPEG-4 container files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_base_media_file_format) use [the exact same container file format as original Apple QuickTime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format) `.mov` files, just with a different fourCC, so "converting" a `.mov` to an `.mp4` file is a NOOP. However if you're asking about transcoding between AVC/HEVC/VVC that's _different_.